# sshd service fails to start

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

I'm not sure why it isn't starting or why its preventing me from connecting, i get this error:

```
sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2013-09-11 08:45:13 BST; 1min 21s ago
  Process: 701 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshd -D (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: Stopping OpenSSH Daemon...
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH Daemon...
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service start request repeated too quickly,    refusing to start.
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH Daemon.
Sep 11 08:45:13 alarmpi systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
```

---

On the advice of #amrith I ran sshd -t which indicated that the key had not been generate . I generated this using ssh-keygen -A on the advice given in this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165382) then running systemctl status showed that I am still not running the Daemon. I've attached the error below, sadly I don't know ho Re-running sshd -t gives no messages now.

```
sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH Daemon.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi sshd[289]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Stopping OpenSSH Daemon...
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH Daemon...
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: sshd.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH Daemon.
Sep 11 12:04:42 alarmpi systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 64):

Try the `sshd` test mode. It may point you to a reason for failure:

```
$ sshd -t
```

Refer to the test mode documentation [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Server).

Comment: Great. I accidentally uninstalled openssh-server and was unaware of that.. `sshd` command not found got me to know that ..

Comment: I didn't know how much more useful information you get by the test mode as compared to what's written in the journal. This gave me the exact line of the configuration files he didn't like and fixing those solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The problem, in our case was that we use a non-standard port for SSH. SELinux can restrict which ports are able to be used by a service. Apparently it gets confused sometimes and forgets that we had allowed that port?

We had to issue the following command to add our port (22222) to the list of available ports

`semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 22222`

Reference: http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/10/15/centos-7-rhel-7-change-openssh-port-number-selinux-enabled/

Answer (score 15):

**Well if you change the SSH port number you have to do some more things in CentOS 7.**

Change SSH port editing ssdh_config file

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

For example change to: **Port 2323**

SELINUX only allow port 22 for ssh. Add new port context 2323. 
If you have't installed do the following

```
yum -y install policycoreutils-python
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2323
```

Check the port context for ssh

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
```

Restart SSHD service

```
systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Add the port to firewall

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=2323/tcp
```

Reload firewall

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Check listening

```
ss -tnlp|grep ssh
```

Try connecting again trough ssh

```
ssh root@<ipaddr> -p 2323
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem but solved it. My configuration is below.

```
PermitRootLogin no
port 22
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 2
AllowUsers ravikanth
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 192.168.1.23
```

The service failed to start so I have just commented out the last line (`#ListenAddress 192.168.1.23`) then my server started successfully.

Note: I have turned off firewall (iptables) and SELinux.

Comment: This fixed it for me too, it looks like my local IP changed. The config file should be at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 4):

Just follow this,

```
mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
```

and

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Why should that be a solution for the problem the OP had?

Comment: I have a similar issue in OpenVZ. I followed this was to fix the issue.

Comment: this was helpful.

Comment: `mkdir -p /var/run/sshd` was the key if `service ssh` was not started previously

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try using the following setting:

```
RestartSec=5s
```

That would force your application to sleep for 5 seconds prior to a restart attempt. You can obviously vary the number of settings.

See [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/centos@centos.org/msg106403.html) for details:

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because it contains useful information about how to fix the issue when the problem is in systemd and not the actual service (sshd in the OP case). I've had services with restart=always fail and not be restarted, several times. This answer might actually solve that issue with systemd. (Eventhough it is not directly related to the OP question).

Comment: Still relevant, as well.  Thanks.  This is helpful across a spectrum of services, especially in a container context.

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot bind any address`

If it tries to bind to a port (eg. by default: 22) below 1024, it needs root privilege to do that. Did you run `service sshd start` or something like that as root? Try editing the sshd.conf configuration file, set the bind address to a port greater than 1024 (eg. 1122) and run it as a simple user!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the easiest solution I came through was to remove `openssh` and install it again.

```
 yum remove openssh
```

and then:

```
 yum install openssh openssh-server openssh-clients
```

then you can start `sshd` service:

```
 service sshd start
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Just disabled SELinux!

Comment: instead of disabling, you can set it to Permissive.